# Github File change notification for PR

Tags: github

I have seen that other people asked the same question, the solution doesn't work for me.

So, I have a repo that developers push files to. 
What I want to be able to do is track one single file in the repo and have an email notification sent when that file has been modified and a PR opened and is open for review. Is this possible? Do I have to setup notification on the repo level or set "watch" for the specific repo/file.

Thank you,
Roland

Comment: What is the solution that you tried? Why it didn’t work? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask